# How to integrate custom authentication provider into IdentityServer4

Tags: identityserver4

Is it possible to somehow extend IdentityServer4 to run custom authentication logic? I have the requirement to validate credentials against a couple of existing custom identity systems and struggle to find an extension point to do so (they use custom protocols).
All of these existing systems have the concept on an API key which the client side knows. The IdentityServer job should now be to validate this API key and also extract some existing claims from the system.
I imagine to do something like this:

```
POST /connect/token
    custom_provider_name=my_custom_provider_1&
    custom_provider_api_key=secret_api_key
```

Then I do my logic to call `my_custom_provider_1`, validate the API key, get the claims and pass them back to the IdentityServer flow to do the rest.

Is this possible?

Comment: You will not be able to use existing clients with identity server unless they are using standard protocols(openid connect, oauth).

Comment: Did you get this working in the end? If so please share how you made it work.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'm assuming you have control over the clients, and the requests they make, so you can make the appropriate calls to your Identity Server.

It *is* possible to use custom authentication logic, after all that is what the `ResourceOwnerPassword` flow is all about: the client passes information to the Connect/token endpoint and you write code to decide what that information means and decide whether this is enough to authenticate that client. You'll definitely be going off the beaten track to do what you want though, because convention says that the information the client passes is a `username` and a `password`.

In your `Startup.ConfigureServices` you will need to add your own implementation of an `IResourceOwnerPasswordValidator`, kind of like this:

```
services.AddTransient<IResourceOwnerPasswordValidator, ResourceOwnerPasswordValidator>();
```

Then in the `ValidateAsync` method of that class you can do whatever logic you like to decide whether to set the `context.Result` to a successful `GrantValidationResult`, or a failed one. One thing that can help you in that method, is that the `ResourceOwnerPasswordValidationContext` has access to the raw request. So any custom fields you add into the original call to the connect/token endpoint will be available to you. This is where you could add your custom fields (provider name, api key etc).

Good luck!

EDIT: The above could work, but is really abusing a standard grant/flow. Much better is the approach found by the OP to use the `IExtensionGrantValidator` interface to roll your own grant type and authentication logic. For example:

Call from client to identity server:

```
POST /connect/token
grant_type=my_crap_grant&
scope=my_desired_scope&
rhubarb=true&
custard=true&
music=ska
```

Register your extension grant with DI:

```cs
services.AddTransient<IExtensionGrantValidator, MyCrapGrantValidator>();
```

And implement your grant validator:

```cs
public class MyCrapGrantValidator : IExtensionGrantValidator
{
    // your custom grant needs a name, used in the Post to /connect/token
    public string GrantType => "my_crap_grant";

    public async Task ValidateAsync(ExtensionGrantValidationContext context)
    {
        // Get the values for the data you expect to be used for your custom grant type
        var rhubarb = context.Request.Raw.Get("rhubarb");
        var custard = context.Request.Raw.Get("custard");
        var music = context.Request.Raw.Get("music");

        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(rhubarb)||string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(custard)||string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(music)
        {
            // this request doesn't have the data we'd expect for our grant type
            context.Result = new     GrantValidationResult(TokenRequestErrors.InvalidGrant);
            return Task.FromResult(false);
        }

        // Do your logic to work out, based on the data provided, whether 
        // this request is valid or not
        if (bool.Parse(rhubarb) && bool.Parse(custard) && music=="ska")
        {
            // This grant gives access to any client that simply makes a 
            // request with rhubarb and custard both true, and has music 
            // equal to ska. You should do better and involve databases and 
            // other technical things
            var sub = "ThisIsNotGoodSub";
            context.Result = new GrantValidationResult(sub,"my_crap_grant");
            Task.FromResult(0);
        }

        // Otherwise they're unauthorised
        context.Result = new GrantValidationResult(TokenRequestErrors.UnauthorizedClient);
        return Task.FromResult(false);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, IResourceOwnerPasswordValidator works as described. However I also discovered the IExtensionGrantValidator which also works work fine by defining a custom grant type for every authentication provider and passing the api key into the extra object when calling RequestCustomGrantAsync. Somehow this feels more natural for my scenario because I don't have to abuse the username/password field. Is this ok to do so?

Comment: Yes that looks like a much better approach, rather than misusing the `password` grant type

Comment: @NKnusperer: could you maybe provide your solution or at least the basic steps? I have a similar situation and I don't get how to use IExtensionGrantValidator. Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: @user4587483 Have a look at my edit for a (crap) example of implementing an `IExtensionGrantValidator`

Comment: Is `IExtensionGrantValidator` still recommended way to do this with the latest IS4?

Comment: @stt106 - i can confirm this approach still works in IdentityServer4.

i also had to provide an IProfileService that returned true for IsActiveAsync() method... otherwise i got "invalid_request" in the json result... and serilog showed the "IdentityServer4.Validation.TokenRequestValidator User has been disabled" error server side.

besides IProfile impl, here's setup code in Startup.cs ConfigureServices() method:
```csharp
services.AddTransient<IProfileService, CustomProfileService>();

services.AddIdentityServer()
.AddProfileService<CustomProfileService>()
// ... etc
;
```

Comment: Do you get this working with the quickstart? There the AccountController is trying to validate the user an the custom PasswordValidator is never called. How did you do this?