# LDAP Authentication Handler ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net-core, ldap, identityserver3, identityserver4, asp.net-authentication

Currently I have to implement an LDAP authentication handler for IdentityServer4 and ASP.Net where a user will login to a site, have IdentityServer handle authentication using an LDAP query and return ticket, token and embedded custom claims. I have started looking at AuthenticationHandler based on the work here https://github.com/aspnet/Security and some work done here: [How to integrate custom authentication provider into IdentityServer4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43809881/how-to-integrate-custom-authentication-provider-into-identityserver4). What I need is some more detailed help in what I should be looking at and what I should be implementing. Please note that I cannot use Active Directory.