# IdentityServer4: What is the Idiomatic Way to Integrate a Custom Source for Authentication and Profile Retrieval?

Tags: c#, identityserver4, identity, extensibility, custom-authentication

Let's say I have to integrate with a legacy enterprise system which maintains users. Assume this enterprise system provides a C# SDK with two methods as follows:

1. Authentication:
   `sdk.Authenticate("Region", "Username", "Password")`
   Note that `Region` is an additional parameter selected by the user at login. So I need to be able to read this custom parameter in addition to the user credentials too. (Yes login would be interactive).
2. Profile Retrieval:
   `sdk.GetProfile(UserId)`

I want to use IdentityServer to generate tokens in the usual manner but use these two methods to implement custom authentication and profile retrieval.

I can see that extending the `IProfileService` I should be able to integrate profile retrieval and population of custom claims. However I see the following multiple extensibility points in the docs but not sure what the best way would be;

1. Quick Start UI's `Account Controller`'s `Login(LoginInputModel model, string button)` method: I should be able to place the `sdk.Authenticate("Region", "Username", "Password")` logic here and just call _signInManager.SignInAsync to sign in the user. But it does not feel as if I'm directly extending IdentityServer4 to add support for another custom authentication provider.
2. IExtensionGrantValidator: 
   [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43830042/454378) and [IdentityServer Docs](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/topics/extension_grants.html) explain a way to do a custom grant which I should be able to use to call `sdk.Authenticate("Region", "Username", "Password")`. But this would mean I'd be using a custom grant type. I need to be able to support existing grant types such as Hybrid. I see support for custom parameters via `context` parameter in the `ValidateAsync(ExtensionGrantValidationContext context)` method
3. IResourceOwnerPasswordValidator: 
   [This IdentityServer doc](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/topics/resource_owner.html) explains how to implement a custom password validator for the Resource Owner flow. But I need to be able to support existing grant types such as Hybrid. I see support for custom parameters via `context` parameter in the `ValidateAsync(ResourceOwnerPasswordValidationContext context)` method
4. External Authenticators: 
   [This IdentityServer doc](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/quickstarts/4_external_authentication.html) explains how to add external authenticators. But I see no `.AddCustom` method for non-standard authenticators. I only see support for popular authenticators such as Google.

What am I missing?

Comment: You need some custom login page to support your additional parameter, so your choice it **1** anyway. Option **4** is for redirecting to an external login page, when you have only an api. Options **2** and **3** are not interactive, so your requirements left you only one option, and i see no problem with it : )

Comment: @d_f is right, the option 1 is most likely what you are looking for here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I chose to go with the first option mentioned in the question which is: Quick Start UI's `Account Controller`'s `Login(LoginInputModel model, string button)` method